# How to clean a specific thing on command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, cmd

I'm wondering is that possible to clean a specific thing on command shell run by a Python script?

E.g a script contains:

```
print ("Hello world")
```

When I double click on this script, cmd will pop up and I'll see `Hello world` on command line. Now I'm wondering, is that possible to clean `Hello World` from shell and write something else on there **while cmd is running**? Like:

```
print ("Hello world")
time.sleep(1)

# a module replace New Text with Hello world
print("New Text")
```

Comment: I think there are special characters to move the cursor in the cmd and delete specific parts

Comment: *a module replace New Text with Hello world* <- please be much more specific about this part. What exactly do you want to happen? Another python program should modify the program that prints out the message?

Comment: Check out the curses module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flush the printed text, don't write a newline at the end but rather a `\r` 
in order to start printing at the beginning of the next line:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # to make it work with Python 2, just in case
import time

print ("Hello world", end='\r', flush=True)
time.sleep(1)
print ("New Text     ", end='\r', flush=True)
time.sleep(1)
print ("Last Text    ")
```

Comment: This is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You may use ANSI escape characters for this:

```
sys.stdout.write("\033[F")  # Cursor up to line
sys.stdout.write("\033[K")  # Clear line
```

Or while this sometimes not works in Windows cmd, try this:

```
sys.stdout.write("\r")  # Move to line beginning
```

Or as you want it:

```
import time

print("Hello world", end="\r")
time.sleep(1)
print("New text   ")  # Trailing slashes to completely override "Hello world"
```